# Return value from useEffect, Only run the hook if something is true

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on code where someone has created custom hooks for context and authentication. I am trying to add a route layout provider and run those hooks inside that component so it only affects particular routes.

RouteLayout Component

```
const routeLayout: React.FC = ():React.ReactElement => {
  useAuthentication();
  //I only want to run the context hook if useAuthentication returns true.
  useContext();

  return (
    <></>
  );
};


export routeLayout
```

Code for useAuthentication

```
export const useAuthenticated = async() : Promise<void> => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const isAuth = async () => {

      //Call API and check if the token is valid
    };
    isAuth();
},[something]);
};
```

How do I return something from useEffect - useAuthentication so I can only run the context code if it is valid token. Please also tell if there is better way to do this

Comment: 1. You can't run a hook conditionally. It will cause an error

Comment: 2. You can't return anything from `useEffect`. You have to assign the result to a state and return a state from the hook

Comment: @Konrad Can you please show me an example?

Comment: @Konrad What can I do then?

Comment: The `useAuthenticated` hook can't be `async` since no React component can `await` it, it should save whatever data locally in state, e.g. `useState` hook, and return the state. The React component can't conditionally call the `useContext` hook, but can conditionally run logic using the returned values from both the `useAuthenticated` and `useContext` hooks. Does this all make sense?

Comment: @DrewReese It does, I am new to React so can you send me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const useAuthenticated = () => {
  // create state
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const isAuth = async () => {
      // assign state
      setAuth(true);
    };
    isAuth();
  }, [setAuth]);

  // return state
  return auth;
};
```

```
const routeLayout: React.FC = (): React.ReactElement => {
  // get auth value
  const auth = useAuthentication();
  // pass auth value to the context
  useContext(auth);

  return <></>;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const routeLayout: React.FC = ():React.ReactElement => {
    useMemo(async () => {
    const isAuth = await apiCall();
    useContext({ isAuth });
}, [something])

    return (
      <></>
    );
  };
```

You can use async here and rap your function in a memo and then await the response in order to know what the hook should do. A prop key within the context to let it know if it should run based on if isAuth is true or not would resolve this.

Comment: This won't work. Hooks can't be called conditionally

Comment: Hooks can only be called in React components and custom React hooks, they cannot be called in nested functions like the `useMemo` callback.